# What algorithm .Net use for searching a pattern in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm studying string searching algorithms now and wondering what algorithm is used for .NET String.Contains function for example.
Reflector shows that this function is used but I have no idea what its name means.

```
private static extern int InternalFindNLSStringEx(IntPtr handle, string localeName, int flags, string source, int sourceCount, int startIndex, string target, int targetCount);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does String.Contains work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769519/how-does-string-contains-work)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s just the naïve string search implementation via a nested loop over the text and the pattern, with O(n·m) runtime.

In particular, the MSDN doesn’t specify the performance of this method so it’s not safe to assume a better performance.

Furthermore, most advanced pattern searching methods are quite specialised for certain string types and while there *are* better general-purpose search algorithms, implementing one in `String.IndexOf` is somewhat of an unnecessary optimisation.

The reason is simple: if you *require* an efficient pattern search then you’ll implement your own anyway, custom-tailored to fit your particular data. So there’s no need to implement something fancy in the general-purpose library.

---

As of 2016 (with the Core CLR source code now available), the implementation is still using a naïve nested loop. This is implemented in [`NewApis::IndexOfString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/utilcode/newapis.cpp#L775) and [`NewApis::FastIndexOfString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/utilcode/newapis.cpp#L577), which are called (via `InternalFindNLSStringEx`) from the managed `String.Contains` and `String.IndexOf` functions.

Comment: Thank you for reasonable answer.

Comment: I could not agree less; why would you implement your own general string search if there is already one in the library?
Furthermore, string searching algorithms are exceptions since there is Boyer-Moore which is so nice (all pro no con) that is deemed standard benchmark. What I mean to say is that usually choosing an algorithm for a library can be really hard, but with strings I would not expect anything less to be used in any library worth anything. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Unreason: in most applications it simply doesn’t matter. Using `Find` for anything but trivial tasks results in complicated logic and code bloat anyway. Better use regular expressions or a parser. Where you *do* need to use pattern finding and where it matters, you rarely deal with Unicode. Often it’s highly specialized like DNA sequences. And *of course* you don’t program that yourself – you use ready-made libraries. But these are specialized and don’t belong in a general framework like the .NET framework.

Comment: @Unreason: and Boyer-Moore depends critically on the size of the alphabet which is forbidding for Unicode. It’s possible to modify the algorithm to use hashing instead but already the parameters are getting murky. I think few people who work on a general framework like .NET know how to get this right (more efficient than the naive search in the general case and 100% bug-free) without making the implementation expensive.

Comment: (cont’d) Finally, Boyer-Moore is by no means the last word; Horspool is often (most of the time?) more efficient (not to mention easier to implement). I’m sure there are modern variants which tweak Horspool even more. And, without having performed any benchmarks, I’ll wager that for most applications (i.e. *relatively* small Unicode strings) naive search outperforms Horspool hands down.

Comment: + for comment - makes sense :) For completeness sake here's another discussion that coincides with your reasoning http://yedda.com/questions/String_IndexOf_search_algorithm_net_1499176185184/

Answer (score 0):

Why using reflector when the [source code](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx) is available?

Comment: That still wont show you any native/internal code, as this method does.

Comment: I was trying to use the source code but it doesn't show me the algorithm. Am I doing something wrong or there is no way to see the real implementation?

Comment: Also you should put thin in a comment, not the answare

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find that method stub, but my best guess is that it local-specific case-folding for case-insensitive searches.