# c# How to Continuously find a byte array inside a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, search, find, byte

I'm trying to continuously find a byte array (byte[]) within a byte array and I found a code that only finds the first occurrence.

**This is where I found the code:** [Find an array (byte[]) inside another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859023/find-an-array-byte-inside-another-array)

**Question:** How can I continuously find a byte array with this code below?

```
        public int SearchBytes(byte[] haystack, byte[] needle)
    {
        int len = needle.Length;
        int limit = haystack.Length - len;
        for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
        {
            int k = 0;
            for (; k < len; k++)
            {
                if (needle[k] != haystack[i + k]) break;
            }
            if (k == len) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? If you want to return a `List<int>` of matches, can't you just change the `return i` to `matches.Add(i)` having declared a `List<int> matches = new List<int>()` to start with?

Comment: By continuously find you mean to find all occurences of a byte sequence withing another byte array?

Comment: @Gnqz Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Have a look at [the algorithm in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252518/boyer-moore-horspool-algorithm-for-all-matches-find-byte-array-inside-byte-arra), with the corrected answer. It uses the Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm, which is very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the method to accept a start index like this:

```
public int SearchBytes(byte[] haystack, byte[] needle, int start_index)
{
    int len = needle.Length;
    int limit = haystack.Length - len;
    for (int i = start_index; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        for (; k < len; k++)
        {
            if (needle[k] != haystack[i + k]) break;
        }
        if (k == len) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The difference is simply that this method accepts a `start_index` and starts the search at this specific index.

Now, you can use it like this:

```
byte[] haystack = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3 };

byte[] needle = new byte[] {1,2,3};

int index = 0;

while (true)
{
    index = SearchBytes(haystack, needle, index);

    if (index == -1)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine("Found at " + index);

    index += needle.Length;
}
```

This loop starts on index 0, then it uses the result of the previous search to set a new index to start the next search.

It adds `needle.Length` to the index so that we start searching immediately after the end of the previously found result.

**UPDATE:**

Here is how this code can be used to create a method that returns the indexes as an array:

```
public int[] SearchBytesMultiple(byte[] haystack, byte[] needle)
{
    int index = 0;

    List<int> results = new List<int>();

    while (true)
    {
        index = SearchBytes(haystack, needle, index);

        if (index == -1)
            break;

        results.Add(index);

        index += needle.Length;
    }

    return results.ToArray();
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
byte[] haystack = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3 };

byte[] needle = new byte[] {1,2,3};

int[] indexes = SearchBytesMultiple(haystack, needle);
```

Comment: I tried your answer and its throwing an exception:  Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: which line throws the exception? Did you take the method code as is? There are two pieces of changes in it.

Comment: This is the exception: if (needle[k] != haystack[i + k]) break;
I took the 'int index = 0' and placed it outside the void (which is a button) and i got an exception, otherwise if i left it as is, it won't find another occurrence.

Comment: Why did you move the `int index = 0`? Is it now an instance variable? How does the code look now?

Comment: It works now, I had to delete the while (true). I'm not sure why that fixed it. Also I had to move the index because it was resetting it to 0 every time you click the button. Here is the fixed version: 

`byte[] haystack = new byte[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1 };
byte[] needle = new byte[] { 1 };
index = SearchBytes(haystack, needle, index); Console.WriteLine("Found at " + index);
index += needle.Length;`

Comment: @JohnSmith, I updated my answer to include the previous code as a method. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Thank you. In C++ I would use the STL function std::search

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could consider using the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), which is extremely performant if the size of `needle[]` or `haystack[]` is large.

However, I wouldn't recommend this for very short `needle[]` or `haystack[]` because the overhead of setting up the offset tables will be higher than just doing a simple linear search.

Here's an implementation that I converted from the Java one on the Wiki page that I linked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public sealed class BoyerMoore
    {
        readonly byte[] needle;
        readonly int[]  charTable;
        readonly int[]  offsetTable;

        public BoyerMoore(byte[] needle)
        {
            this.needle      = needle;
            this.charTable   = makeByteTable(needle);
            this.offsetTable = makeOffsetTable(needle);
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> Search(byte[] haystack)
        {
            if (needle.Length == 0)
                yield break;

            for (int i = needle.Length - 1; i < haystack.Length;)
            {
                int j;

                for (j = needle.Length - 1; needle[j] == haystack[i]; --i, --j)
                {
                    if (j != 0)
                        continue;

                    yield return i;
                    i += needle.Length - 1;
                    break;
                }

                i += Math.Max(offsetTable[needle.Length - 1 - j], charTable[haystack[i]]);
            }
        }

        static int[] makeByteTable(byte[] needle)
        {
            const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 256;
            int[] table = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
                table[i] = needle.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < needle.Length - 1; ++i)
                table[needle[i]] = needle.Length - 1 - i;

            return table;
        }

        static int[] makeOffsetTable(byte[] needle)
        {
            int[] table = new int[needle.Length];
            int lastPrefixPosition = needle.Length;

            for (int i = needle.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (isPrefix(needle, i + 1))
                    lastPrefixPosition = i + 1;

                table[needle.Length - 1 - i] = lastPrefixPosition - i + needle.Length - 1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < needle.Length - 1; ++i)
            {
                int slen = suffixLength(needle, i);
                table[slen] = needle.Length - 1 - i + slen;
            }

            return table;
        }

        static bool isPrefix(byte[] needle, int p)
        {
            for (int i = p, j = 0; i < needle.Length; ++i, ++j)
                if (needle[i] != needle[j])
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        static int suffixLength(byte[] needle, int p)
        {
            int len = 0;

            for (int i = p, j = needle.Length - 1; i >= 0 && needle[i] == needle[j]; --i, --j)
                ++len;

            return len;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's some test code:

```
byte[] haystack = new byte[1000];
byte[] needle   = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

for (int i = 100; i <= 900; i += 100)
    Array.Copy(needle, 0, haystack, i, needle.Length);

var searcher = new BoyerMoore(needle);

foreach (int index in searcher.Search(haystack))
    Console.WriteLine(index);
```