# How to search for an int[] in List<int[]> and remove item in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

Supposing I have a `List<int>` its easy to search for an integer, lets say `6`

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
if(list.Contains(6))
   Console.Write("6 exists");
```

but how would I search for a `int[]` in a `List<int[]>`

```
List<int[]> example = new List<int[]>();
example.Add(new int[4]{0,1,2,3});
example.Add(new int[4]{10,11,12,13});
example.Add(new int[4]{20,21,22,23});
```

How to search for `{0,1,2,3}` and also delete that index on list?

```
int[] toFind = new int[4]{0,1,2,3};
foreach (int[] item in list)
{
   if(item.Length == toFind.Length)
   {
       bool found = false;
       for(int i=0; i < item.Length;i++)
       {
          if(item[i] == toFind[i])   
          {
              found = true;
          }
           else
          {
              found = false;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I was trying to first compare wanted item  length with each item length, the compare each item on array.
There must be a better way to do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`FindIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex) and the Linq extension [`SequenceEquals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(arr =>  arr.Length == toFind.Length && arr.SequenceEqual(toFind));
if (index >= 0) list.RemoveAt(index);
```

Note that `SequenceEqual` returns `true` only if the elements in the sequence are in the same order. So `{1,2,3,4}` is not the same as `{2,1,4,3}`.

Comment: Note this will be relatively slow for searching large data sources. [Using the Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252518/boyer-moore-horspool-algorithm-for-all-matches-find-byte-array-inside-byte-arra) can give you significant performance gains.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree, this is not the fastest way. Maybe OP specifies in the question what "better way" means: faster, more readable or something else.

Comment: @Edgar I added a length check to make it faster. now I actually can't think of an algorithm to make it even faster. Unless you want to use this many times for different arrays checking against the _same list of arrays_. In this case, some way of hashing/indexing the arrays in the list could help. But if the overhead will pay off really depends on how often you really search in the same list. For a small number of searches I think my code does not leave much room for optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to change a List object in a foreach loop, but you can use a for loop instead.

```
private void removeFromList(List<int[]> list, int[] compare) {
   for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
      if (list[i] == compare) {
         list.RemoveAt(i);
       }
     }
}
```